# there is @adonisjs/drive at adonisjs 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

recent im using adonis 5 for the backend,in my current project i need to use the drive storage and return the file for download on the frontend this is posible at adonisjs 4.1 with @adonisjs/drive but i not found a equivalent method at adonis 5 ¿i can to use @adonisjs/drive in adonisjs 5? or ¿anoter library what i can to use? ¿there is a equivalent method at adonis 5? i read the documentation but i only found the request file method and not a method for return a file to frontend .

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Adonis Drive has not been converted to Adonis 5 at the time of this writing (November 24th 2020). Thus, you cannot use this package with version 5 right now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the context response, as indicated in this section
https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/response#download

```
// app/Controllers/Http/FilesController.ts
 
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'
import Application from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Application'

export default class FilesController {
  /**
   *
   * @param response
   * @param params
   */
  public async download({ response, params }: HttpContextContract) {
    // projectname/tmp/uploads/world.txt
    const filePath = Application.tmpPath(`uploads/${params.name}`)
    return response.download(filePath)
  }
}

// start/routes.ts

// example http://127.0.0.1:3333/file/world.txt
Route.get('/file/:name', 'FilesController.download')
```